# Disable introspection query in graphql java tools spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql

I am facing issues while disabling the introspection query in a spring boot graphql project on a get endpoint query parameter.

I was replicating this by using one of the GET endpoint and using the below parameter

```
baseurl/servicename/insight_graph?query=fragment+FullType+on+__Type+{++kind++name++description++fields(includeDeprecated%3a+true)+{++++name++++description++++args+{++++++...InputValue++++}++++type+{++++++...TypeRef++++}++++isDeprecated++++deprecationReason++}++inputFields+{++++...InputValue++}++interfaces+{++++...TypeRef++}++enumValues(includeDeprecated%3a+true)+{++++name++++description++++isDeprecated++++deprecationReason++}++possibleTypes+{++++...TypeRef++}}fragment+InputValue+on+__InputValue+{++name++description++type+{++++...TypeRef++}++defaultValue}fragment+TypeRef+on+__Type+{++kind++name++ofType+{++++kind++++name++++ofType+{++++++kind++++++name++++++ofType+{++++++++kind++++++++name++++++++ofType+{++++++++++kind++++++++++name++++++++++ofType+{++++++++++++kind++++++++++++name++++++++++++ofType+{++++++++++++++kind++++++++++++++name++++++++++++++ofType+{++++++++++++++++kind++++++++++++++++name++++++++++++++}++++++++++++}++++++++++}++++++++}++++++}++++}++}}query+IntrospectionQuery+{++__schema+{++++queryType+{++++++name++++}++++mutationType+{++++++name++++}++++types+{++++++...FullType++++}++++directives+{++++++name++++++description++++++locations++++++args+{++++++++...InputValue++++++}++++}++}}

and with the below dependencies

   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphiql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

This works pretty well when we request the same using post and with the below request body and using graphql.tools.introspection-enabled=false and

```
    POST baseurl/servicename/insight_graph
    
        [
    {
        "operationName": "IntrospectionQuery",
        "variables": {},
        "query": "query IntrospectionQuery {__schema {queryType { name },mutationType { name },subscriptionType { name },types {...FullType},directives {name,description,args {...InputValue},onOperation,onFragment,onField}}}\nfragment FullType on __Type {kind,name,description,fields(includeDeprecated: true) {name,description,args {...InputValue},type {...TypeRef},isDeprecated,deprecationReason},inputFields {...InputValue},interfaces {...TypeRef},enumValues(includeDeprecated: true) {name,description,isDeprecated,deprecationReason},possibleTypes {...TypeRef}}\nfragment InputValue on __InputValue {name,description,type { ...TypeRef },defaultValue}\nfragment TypeRef on __Type {kind,name,ofType {kind,name,ofType {kind,name,ofType {kind,name}}}}"
    }
    ]
```

I also tried this via spring filters and it works fine
Is there any way to disable introspection via spring boot property for this?